# How to save cluster for later display

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, cluster-computing, hierarchical-clustering

I'm using scipy for clustering 10k of chemical data. At first, I use pdist() to calculate pairwise distances and then ward() for the clustering. Next, I combined 2 dendrograms and a matrix which gave me a heatmap visualization of the clusters. For my dendrograms, I labelled the data with groups of colours which gave me coloured labels for the cluster's leaves. It all runs well in my windows local machine when I tested with using the subset of data.

However, when I want to implement the code for all 10k using my university HPC computing which run on Linux, apparently it gives error that seems to have a problem with the matplotlib AGG (which I'm supposed to use if using the HPC).

My question is, has anyone face the same problem when using AGG? And, is there any way so that I can save my generated cluster (Z) so that I can use my local machine for displaying the plots rather than having a problem of displaying it in HPC?

### Edit

Thank you for the replies in the comments. The actual error when I debug the batch job is below:

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
Missing separate debuginfo for /home/lip13lm/.conda/envs/rdkit-/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/../../../../libiomp5.so

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
generate (this=<optimized out>, len=840, y=1836238, x=1563, span=0xe91b160) at extern/agg24-svn/include/agg_span_image_filter_rgba.h:68
68  extern/agg24-svn/include/agg_span_image_filter_rgba.h: No such file or directory.
#0  generate (this=<optimized out>, len=840, y=1836238, x=1563, span=0xe91b160) at extern/agg24-svn/include/agg_span_image_filter_rgba.h:68
#1  generate (len=840, y=629, x=0, span=<optimized out>, this=0x7fffffffba40) at extern/agg24-svn/include/agg_span_converter.h:45
```

In HPC, my environment use Python 3.5.3 and matplotlib 2.0.0.

It was successfully run when I tried to plot simple dendrogram using same amount of data in the beginning using the HPC. The error only occurred when I edit my code to integrate two dendrograms with matrix for heatmap and color labels. So I assume amount of data is not an issue here since I've tested it before with the same backend.

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')

X = dist.pdist(C,coef)
Y = squareform(X)
Z = ward(X)

print ("Starting dendogram heatmap plotting...")
plt.clf() # plt.clf() clears the entire current figure with all its axes, 
          # but leaves the window opened, such that it may be reused for other plots
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(14, 15))

# Compute and plot FIRST (1) dendrogram
# add_axes(left,bottom,width,height)
ax1=fig.add_axes([0.09,0.1,0.2,0.6])
Z1=dendrogram(
    Z,
    color_threshold=30,
    orientation='left',
    above_threshold_color="grey"
)
ax1.set_xticks([])
ax1.set_yticks([])
ax1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)

# Compute and plot SECOND (2) dendrogram
ax2=fig.add_axes([0.3,0.71,0.6,0.2])
plt.title('Ward Hierarchical Clustering Dendrogram MDDR\n\n [ size: %d bits - coefficient: %s ]\n' %(size,coef))
Z2=dendrogram(
    Z,
    color_threshold=30,
    no_labels=True,
    above_threshold_color="grey"
)
ax2.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
plt.ylabel('distance')

# Method 1: Assign bar color label below dendogram
color=[classes[k] for k in Z2['leaves']]
b=.1*Z[-2,2] # adjust the height of each bar
plt.bar(
        np.arange(N)*10,
        np.ones(N)*b,
        bottom=-b,
        width=10,
        color=color,
        edgecolor='none',
        align='center'
)
plt.gca().set_ylim((-b,None))

# Plot distance matrix
axmatrix=fig.add_axes([0.3,0.1,0.6,0.6])
idx1=Z1['leaves']
idx2=Z2['leaves']
Y=Y[idx1,:]
Y=Y[:,idx2]
# http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html
im=axmatrix.matshow(Y, aspect='auto', origin='lower', cmap=pylab.cm.gist_earth)
axmatrix.set_xticks([]) # disable matrix x-axis ticks & label
axmatrix.set_yticks([]) # disable matrix y-axis ticks & label
axmatrix.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
axmatrix.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
axmatrix.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
axmatrix.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)

# Plot colorbar
axcolorbar=fig.add_axes([0.91,0.1,0.02,0.6])
cb=pylab.colorbar(im, cax=axcolorbar)
cb.outline.set_visible(False)

# Configure legend
# http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/named_colors.html
i_patch=mpatches.Patch(color='black', label='Inactives')
t_patch=mpatches.Patch(color='tan', label='Thrombin')
s_patch=mpatches.Patch(color='teal', label='SubP')
r_patch=mpatches.Patch(color='lightpink', label='Renin')
p_patch=mpatches.Patch(color='salmon', label='PKC')
h_patch=mpatches.Patch(color='olive', label='HIVP')
d_patch=mpatches.Patch(color='aquamarine', label='D2')
c_patch=mpatches.Patch(color='mediumslateblue', label='COX')
a_patch=mpatches.Patch(color='gold', label='AT1')
z_patch=mpatches.Patch(color='limegreen', label='5HT3')
y_patch=mpatches.Patch(color='orange', label='5HT1A')
x_patch=mpatches.Patch(color='orchid', label='5HT')

# Plot legend
# add_axes(left,bottom,width,height)
axlegend=fig.add_axes([0.04,0.71,0.2,0.2])
axlegend.axis('off')
axlegend.legend(handles=[x_patch,
                    y_patch,
                    z_patch,
                    a_patch,
                    c_patch,
                    d_patch,
                    h_patch,
                    p_patch,
                    r_patch,
                    s_patch,
                    t_patch,
                    i_patch,],
                    title='Activity Class\n')
print ("Dendogram heatmap plotting completed...")

# save dendogram
print ("Saving dendogram...")
# output = "C:\Users\Lucy\knime-workspace\Experiment File - Clustering\Output\New\cluster_%d_%s.png" %(size,coef)
output = "/home/lip13lm/cluster/output/cluster_%d_%s.png" %(size,coef)
fig.savefig(output, format='png')
print ("Dendogram saved")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! You need to provide more information than that, like the actual error that is thrown, and the library versions you are using. Anyhow, you can always save the model and load it on a desktop for visualization, for that try [the manual](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html).

Comment: You need to understand and apply the concept of a [mcve]. Not only for posting questions here, but also for debugging your code on the cluster. That way you first need to find out if the problem is due to the (large amount of) actual data or the use of a specific backend. In case it's due to the backend, you will find help here by posting the minimal example code here. Remember to include the full error traceback when  [edit]ing your question.

Comment: I said you should edit your question. I now did that for you! Please delete your "answer"!

Comment: I'm really sorry @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I thought it's too long so I put it there. But how do I delete it? I mean which one should I delete? I'm confused. Which one is the "answer" you meant by?